# Fetching model with one-many relationship and parse

Tags: javascript, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I have a one-many relationship of Cells-Synonyms (Biology, not Excel):

Cell.js

```
require('./Synonym');
const model = myBookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'cells',
  // Relations
  synonyms() {
    return this.hasMany('Synonym');
  },
});
export const Cell = myBookshelf.model('Cell', model);
```

Synonym.js

```
require('./Cell');
const model = myBookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'synonyms',
  // Relations
  cell() {
    return this.belongsTo('Cell');
  },
});
export const Synonym = myBookshelf.model('Synonym', model);
```

I've overwritten the parse function to camelize each key.

baseModel

```
...
const bookshelf = generateBookshelf(knexInstance);
myBookshelf.Model = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  ...
  camelCase(attributes) {
    const self = this;
    const attrs = {};
    _.each(attributes, (value, key) => {
      attrs[camelize(key)] = value;
    });
    return attrs;
  },
  parse(attributes) {
    return this.camelCase(attributes);
  }
});
```

When I try to query for cells and get their related synonyms (using ES7 async/await) ...

```
let cells = await Cell.fetchAll({ withRelated: ['synonyms'] });
cells = cells.toJSON();
```

everything works as expected. The cells object has all of the synonyms for the given cell. However the following code returns all of the synonyms, but each has an empty cell key:

```
let synonyms = await Synonym.fetchAll({ withRelated: ['cell'] });
synonyms = synonyms.toJSON();
```

**If I remove the camelizing of each key (remove the parse function), this code works properly.** I've tried adding a `cellId` reference (instead of the default `cell_id`) on Synonym model and haven't had any luck. I could just use knex, but I would rather figure this out. I've looked into overwriting serialize, but I don't think thats the correct place to fix this.

Looking at the debug logs from knex, the cells are retrieved from the database, they're just lost somewhere in the process of fetching or serializing.

```
{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  bindings: [],
  sql: 'select `synonyms`.* from `synonyms`' }
{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  bindings:
  [
    4, 6, 11, 19, 38, 37, 39, 41, 43, 46, 44, 45, 51, 54, 66, 71, 85,
    91, 97, 114, 113, 118, 116, 119, 123, 126, 142, 143, 147, 160, 161
  ],
  sql: 'select `cells`.* from `cells` where `cells`.`id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' }
```

I apologize if this is a little confusing. I can clarify further if needed. Thanks.

**Edit:**

The lists of cells and synonyms are too long to show, so I've shown a few here as an example:

**cells.toJSON()**

```
[{
    id: 1,
    name: "184A1",
    lincsId: "LCL-2080",
    source: "ATCC",
    createdAt: "2016-05-09T18:57:04.044Z",
    updatedAt: "2016-05-09T18:57:04.044Z",
    synonyms: []
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "184B5",
    lincsId: "LCL-2081",
    source: "ATCC",
    createdAt: "2016-05-09T18:57:04.046Z",
    updatedAt: "2016-05-09T18:57:04.046Z",
    synonyms: []
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: 5637,
    lincsId: "LCL-1702",
    source: "ATCC",
    createdAt: "2016-05-09T18:57:04.047Z",
    updatedAt: "2016-05-09T18:57:04.047Z",
    synonyms: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "5637(LCL-1702)",
        cellId: 3,
        createdAt: "2016-05-09T18:57:04.256Z",
        updatedAt: null
    }]
}, {
    id: 4,
    name: "600MPE",
    lincsId: "LCL-2073",
    source: "H.S. Smith (California Pacific Medical Center)",
    createdAt: "2016-05-09T18:57:04.047Z",
    updatedAt: "2016-05-09T18:57:04.047Z",
    synonyms: []
}, {
    id: 5,
    name: "647-V",
    lincsId: "LCL-1708",
    source: "Leibniz Institute DSMZ-German Collection of Microorganisms and Cell Cultures",
    createdAt: "2016-05-09T18:57:04.048Z",
    updatedAt: "2016-05-09T18:57:04.048Z",
    synonyms: []
}]
```

**synonyms.toJSON()**

```
[{
    id: 1,
    name: "5637(LCL-1702)",
    cellId: 3,
    createdAt: "2016-05-09T18:57:04.256Z",
    updatedAt: null,
    cell: {}
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "A-375",
    cellId: 6,
    createdAt: "2016-05-09T18:57:04.263Z",
    updatedAt: null,
    cell: {}
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: "AU-565",
    cellId: 11,
    createdAt: "2016-05-09T18:57:04.273Z",
    updatedAt: null,
    cell: {}
}, {
    id: 4,
    name: "CaSki",
    cellId: 19,
    createdAt: "2016-05-09T18:57:04.290Z",
    updatedAt: null,
    cell: {}
}, {
    id: 5,
    name: "HCC-1395",
    cellId: 37,
    createdAt: "2016-05-09T18:57:04.340Z",
    updatedAt: null,
    cell: {}
}]
```

You can see that the cells that have synonyms are loaded properly, however each synonym's cell key is an empty object and they should be populated with a cell.

Comment: Can you add the results of `cells.toJSON();` and `synonyms.toJSON();`? It'll be simpler if we can see exactly where you have a problem (;

Comment: See edits for `cells.toJSON();` and `synonyms.toJSON();`. Thanks.